# ref foreach with List

Tags: c#

Why can't `ref var` be used within a `foreach` loop that iterates a `List<T>`?

```
Random rand = new();

// This is fine
Span<int> numbers = new int[] { 3, 14, 15, 92, 6 };
foreach (ref var number in numbers)
{
    number = rand.Next();
}

// This is not fine
List<int> nums = new() { 3, 14, 15, 92, 6 };
foreach (ref var number in nums)
{
    number = rand.Next();
}
```

Comment: spans and arrays have direct correlation to their data - `List<T>` wraps the array

Comment: The answer to the linked dupe doesn't address why this works for a `Span<T>`.

Comment: Why do I need to use ref for foreach loop? your question doesn't have any sense at all

Comment: @Serge to remove the need to write a more verbose loop like span has the option for. For example, this afternoon I was trying to convert a list of angles from 0 - 360 to -180 - 180. If it was a span of angles instead, it would have required less code

Comment: @Serge My main confusion was why the behaviour of foreach is not consistent between the different collection types

Comment: @Dan It is not about collection types It is about Span<int>. What prevented you to convert list to array, since array supports Span? or better to use just a for loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the `Span<T>` is equipped with an enumerator that has a `ref` `Current` property, and the `List<T>` isn't.

[`Span<T>.Enumerator.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.enumerator.current) property:

```
public ref T Current { get; }
```

[`List<T>.Enumerator.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.enumerator.current) property:

```
public T Current { get; }
```

If you want, you can get access to the internal storage of a `List<T>` with the [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan) method.

---

**Update:** Actually as @GuruStron pointed out in a comment, the C# compiler doesn't even use the [`Span<T>.Enumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.enumerator) struct, and instead it translates a `foreach` loop to a fast `while` loop. For example the code below:

```
foreach (ref int item in span)
{
    //...
}
```

...[is translated](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAGUAOBDAdgHgJZYAuAfAAQDOmWpAvKVgKYDupBhA2gLqkDepAzABpScACzC4AVmEBOGMIBspAL4BuZADMA9gCcGGAMYALUgAo9G1kVaEGAWysUqASmQ9kpT6QD03gHQByMrIQA=) to:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < span.Length)
{
    ref int item = ref span[i];
    //...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Also based on the [decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWsBKBDAdgCYD2AtogE4GGIC8i+ApgO4AUAlJjAMoAOBAHgCW+AC4A+BgFdSAI0YUAznQYtEI0QG0AuogDeiAMwAaRGlMQArKYCcYUwDZEAXy4AzYhUa4AxgAtEVi83RAA3XAppOQV1fCj5JXZYPVhENPiY+ioiADoAOUYAD1EOLmcsGAAZIUVRYTFJfBlleiY2dn0jC1QLa0Q7RxcuWA8vXwDWcMim6MiRKMUkmBSYdOQIG1YZhM5YcpggA===) in this case it is not even used.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1085 :

> Proposal: Support Span and ReadOnlySpan in foreach, such that:
>
> ```
> foreach (T item in span)
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
> {
>     T item = span[i];
>     ...
> }
> ```

If it is implemented with a for-loop, it makes sense to handle the ref.

Also from the [Span.Enumerator Struct Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.enumerator?view=net-6.0):

> Unlike some other enumerator structures in .NET, the
> Span.Enumerator:
>
> - Does not implement the IEnumerator or IEnumerator interface. This is because Span.Enumerator is a ref struct.

Answer (score 0):

See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay

*emphasis added*

> The Span indexer takes advantage of a C# language feature introduced in C# 7.0 called ref returns. The indexer is declared with a “ref T” return type, which provides semantics like that of indexing into arrays, **returning a reference to the actual storage location** rather than returning a copy of what lives at that location

```cs
public ref T this[int index] { get { ... } }
```

> The impact of this ref-returning indexer is most obvious via example, such as by comparing it with the List indexer, **which is not ref returning**. Here’s an example:

```cs
struct MutableStruct { public int Value; }
...
Span<MutableStruct> spanOfStructs = new MutableStruct[1];
spanOfStructs[0].Value = 42;
Assert.Equal(42, spanOfStructs[0].Value);
var listOfStructs = new List<MutableStruct> { new MutableStruct() };
listOfStructs[0].Value = 42; // Error CS1612: the return value is not a variable
```